# imagecube js cube rotation error

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, cube

I have small issue with the imagecube jquery plugin. http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html

I've gotten it to work just fine on the homepage with three UNLINKED images. When I put links around them, the upward rotation goes wonky. Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance. Link to follow:

http://www.bigideaadv.com/a-z/

Comment: tbh, a simple fade or slide animation would look nicer and smoother.

Comment: I agree but that's not what the client wants though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `onclick` attribute with `window.location.href=">insert url here<"` for each image with a css `cursor: pointer;` instead wrapping an anker-tag:

html:

```
<div id="image_carousel2">
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide1_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" onclick="window.location.href='/a-z/generic';" />
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide2_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" onclick="window.location.href='/a-z/about-a-and-z';" />
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide3_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" onclick="window.location.href='/a-z/operations';" />
</div>
```

css:

```
#image_carousel2 img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CH7RT/).

Comment: Not necessarily the answer I was looking for but your solution works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scessor's solution is probably the way to go but out of interest, you could also dynamically wrap and unwrap the images in `<a>` tags at each rotation. imageCube's beforeRotate and afterRotate handlers make this possible.

HTML:

```
<div id="image_carousel2" style="width: 960px; height:353px; left:-10px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; background:transparent !important;">
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide1_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" url="http://www.bigideaadv.com/a-z/generic" />
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide2_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" url="http://www.bigideaadv.com/a-z/about-a-and-z" />
    <img src="/a-z/./images/slide3_alt.jpg" width="960" height="353" url="http://www.bigideaadv.com/a-z/operations" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image_carousel2').imagecube({
        direction: 'up',
        expansion: 25,
        segments: 15,
        reduction: 30,
        speed: 1000,
        pause: 7000,
        shading: false,
        //Before rotate, remove wrapping anchor (if it exists) from current img.
        beforeRotate: function startRotate(current, next) { 
            if(current.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {//Safety
                $(current).unwrap();//Remove the wrapping anchor.
            }
        },
        //After rotate, wrap next img in its anchor 
        afterRotate: function endRotate(current, next) { 
            var $next = $(next);
            $next.wrap($next.data('anchor'));//Wrap the next img in its anchor.
        }
    });
    //Now create an <a> node for each img in the cube,
    //and save as a .data() property of its <img> node.
    //This allows reuse of <a> nodes, avoiding the need to 
    //(re)create them dynamically at each rotation.
    $('#image_carousel2 img').each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $a = $('<a>').attr('href', $this.attr('url'));
        $this.data('anchor', $a);
        if(i==0){ $this.wrap($a); }//Wrap the first node in its anchor.
    });
});
```

As you might expect, the HTML is simplified but the js is more complicated.

Please note that this solution employs custom `<img ... url="...">` attributes, so the page will probably fail to validate in most validators.